# How to make a file live which is previously defunct

Tags: accurev

There was a defunct file in a stream. I just revert it to backed version in stream, now i can't see that file, what happened to the actual file? how do i obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

Since that file was in 'defunct' state, when i clicked 'revert to backed version', it got removed from the stream (the purge).
I was able to bring that file back to stream. It is still in 'defunct' state, however the version is increased by 1.

Here are the steps that I followed to bring it back to stream:

1. Get the eID (element ID) of the file - to get this, browse to stream and see the history- you should be able to see transaction as 'purge' for this file. From properties of the file, you'll get eID.
2. In command prompt, change to work-space directory of the stream where you reverted the file. Type the below command:

   accurev co -v <\stream_name>\1 -e <\ID>

   where: 
   <\stream_name>\1" is the latest version of the file.
   <\ID> is eID.
3. Go to work-space through GUI, you should now able to see the file. Now it should be promoted to appear in stream.

Comment: there should not be '\' before stream_name and ID. the correct command should be: accurev co -v <stream_name>\<version> -e <ID>

Comment: Yes. I did try that, but it didn't worked for me. When I run undefunct command with eID, it said, no such file exist.